# Error writing to firebase. App keeps crashing

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So, I am new to android and firebase. I am trying to create a messaging app. But as soon as I click the send button my app crashes. I know exactly where the app is crashing. It is crashing right after I click the send button where I am trying to put data on the database. Checked Logcat and everything still can't figure out how to fix it. Heres the code of MainActivity.java

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private Button sendButton;
private TextView editMessage;
private ListView messageList;

private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference qDatabaseReference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    try {
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        qDatabaseReference = qDatabaseReference.getRef().child("messages");
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Database Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    sendButton = findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    editMessage = findViewById(R.id.messageEdit);
    messageList = findViewById(R.id.messageList);

    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Message message = new Message("user","TEST");
            //app crashes here at the line below
            qDatabaseReference.push().setValue(message);
            editMessage.setText("");
        }
    });
}
}
```

Code of my Message class

```
public class Message {

private int maxLength = 1000;

private String name;
private String text;

Message(){
    name = null;
    text = null;
}

Message(String name, String message){
    this.name = name;
    this.text = message;
}
}
```

Finally found the error in LogCat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.push()' on a null object reference
    at com.codeswingstudios.codewise.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:42)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5293)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21660)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6100)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:859)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
```

Comment: can you please post logcat?

Comment: posting logcat would be a bit difficult cause I use a physical device to test my app, so you know there's a lot going on there.

Comment: without that it is difficult to say what are you doing wrong

Comment: finally found errors in logcat, if you can help now.

Comment: you are getting nullpointer here i supose. qDatabaseReference = qDatabaseReference.getRef().child("messages"); So try inspect this variable to see if you got a valid object!

Comment: guess finally found the error. In qDatabaseReference = qDatabaseReference.getRef().child("messages"); I am getting reference from the reference variable itself. Time to serialize the message class now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @AliHussam this is a little off topic, but you can restrict your logcat to only current debuggable application logs so it would only pick your applications log from drop down menu on right.

Comment: Glad you shared. I'll do it the next time I use Logcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try initializing your DatabaseReference like this:

```
DatabaseReference qDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("messages");
```

Comment: guess finally found the error. In qDatabaseReference = qDatabaseReference.getRef().child("messages"); I am getting reference from the reference variable itself instead of firebaseDatabase. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry to say, I can't because of the low repo.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the try and Catch block around the reference initialization and you are trying to get reference on reference. Replace `qDatabaseReference.getReference()` with `firebaseDatabase.getReference()`

```
   firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
   qDatabaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("messages");
```

Hope it is helping